# Convert SQL DDL statements to JSON format

Tags: javascript, geojson

I want to  convert SQL DDL statements to JSON format. Can you please provide the JSON format for the below script?

```
CREATE TABLE LME_TABLES_DB.AD_AGNCY_ORG

(
    AD_AGNCY_NBR VARCHAR(20) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC NOT NULL,
    PARENT_ADVERTISING_AGENCY_NUMB VARCHAR(20) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC,
    AD_AGNCY_NM VARCHAR(50) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC,
    PARTY_ID INTEGER,
    PARTY_SUBTYPE_CD CHAR(1) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC,
    ORG_TYPE_CD CHAR(3) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC,
    CREATE_DTTM TIMESTAMP(6),
    UPDT_DTTM TIMESTAMP(6),
    CUSTOMER_ID VARCHAR(20) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC
)

UNIQUE PRIMARY INDEX XPKAD_AGENCY_ORGANIZATION(AD_AGNCY_NBR, ORG_TYPE_CD);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't seen a direct converter. The workaround could be SQL DDL convert to XSD (xml). Then XML map to JSON.

This tool might be able to do part of it or all you want. 
http://www.liquibase.org/
Let me know if you still working on it!

Answer (score -1):

You will need to use some SQL DDL parser that will create you an AST of it, then you can iterate over that AST and generate what ever you want.

On of the common JS parsers is [PEG.js](https://pegjs.org/). There are [some](https://github.com/alsotang/sql.pegjs) NPM packages that defined the SQL DDL in PEG grammar, so you can use these parsers.